# Partioning points into equal groups from their average

Tags: r, group-by, cluster-analysis, partitioning, partition

I have a set of points such as this, and I am trying to group or cluster them into four groups of equal size based on their distance to their mean.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50, 0, 1),
                 y = rnorm(50, -0, 0.7))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 0.7, intercept = 0) +
  geom_abline(slope = -0.7, intercept = 0)
```

[image]

In this case, I would want each point to be assigned a group based on how far they are with respect to the average (here it would be `(0,0)`) and whether this distance trends more up, down, left or right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50, 0, 1),
                 y = rnorm(50, -0, 0.7),
                 center = rep(0,50))  # not really needed 
df$v1 <- -df$x^2     # vector one 0(center) - df$x2
df$v2 <- -df$y^2     # vector two 0(center) - df$y2
df$dist = df$v1 + df$v2  
df$len = sqrt(abs(df$dist)) #lenght of vector betwen center and point
df$group = cut(df$len, 10,labels = paste("Level",LETTERS[1:10])) # grouping into 10 bins

df<-df %>% mutate(posit= case_when(x < mean(x) & y < mean(y) ~ "A", 
                              x > mean(x) & y  > mean(y) ~ "B",
                              x <mean(x) & y  >mean(y) ~ "C",
                              x >mean(x) & y  <  mean(y) ~ "D"))             

ggplot(data = df ) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y,col= group, shape= posit, size=2)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept =mean(df$x))+
  geom_abline(slope = -0.0, intercept =mean(df$y))
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Do you know how this divide could be done diagonally? I'm trying to split the data something closer to how it looks in my graph?